# PHP inserting text from a file into array

Tags: php, arraylist

I have a text file with cities and population and a php program that should read the text file and insert the text into array while taking into account that the city should be key and the population is value of the array and the program has to sort the array by the value and to print its keys and values in table format.

Example data:

```
Tokyo   39105000
Jakarta 35362000
Delhi   31870000
Manila  23971000
Sao Paulo   22495000
Seoul   22394000
Mumbai  22186000
Shanghai    22118000
Mexico City 21505000
Guangzhou   21489000
```

This is the code:

```
    <?php
    $fileHandler = fopen("Info_array.txt", "rb");
    $data = [];

    while (!feof($fileHandler) ) {
        // read file row
        $row = fgets($fileHandler);

        $index = count($data);

        // explode array by space
        $data[$index] = explode(' ', $row);

        // explode data[$index][0] by '.', then insert into array in index 0 & 1
        array_splice($data[$index], 0, 1, explode('.', $data[$index][0]));
    }

    // sort array by array index 1
    usort($data, function ($prev, $next) {
        if ($prev[1] == $next[1]) {
            return 0;
        }

        return ($prev[1] < $next[1]) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    fclose($fileHandler);
?>

<table class="heavyTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Population</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($data as $item): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $item[0] . '.' . $item[1] ?></td>
                <td><?= $item[2] ?></td>
                <td><?= $item[1] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I currently get error:

```
Warning: Undefined array key 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexercise.php on line 20

Warning: Undefined array key 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexercise.php on line 20

Warning: Undefined array key 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexercise.php on line 20

Warning: Undefined array key 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexercise.php on line 20
```

Any advices on how to do this will be very much appreciated, i'm struggling from a few days now.

Comment: it's seems to be tabs and not spaces

Comment: Maybe take a look at [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read in your file

Comment: I changed that and it still doesnt work, getting same error.

Comment: Got an error with using fgetscv also:
`
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: feof(): Argument #1 ($stream) must be of type resource, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexercise.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexercise.php(6): feof(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpexercise.php on line 6
` i suppose im not using the function correctly, can you please give example code?

Comment: The link I posted has an example already

Comment: By reformatting the contents of the text file, with tabs as a separator, fgetcsv works fine (2 fields in line 1: Tokyo and 39105000, etc.). You should determine the character that acts as a separator in your file. Possible to have the exact source?

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/c9849

Answer (score 0):

Posting solution:

```
<?php
 $fileHandler = fopen("Info_array.txt", "rb");
 $data = array();

 while (!feof($fileHandler) ) {
 // read file row
 $row = fgets($fileHandler);

 // explode array by tab
 $temp = explode('\t', $row);
 $data += [$temp[0] => $temp[1]];
 //array_push($data, $temp[0], $temp[1]);
 }

 fclose($fileHandler);

 arsort($data);
?>
<table class="heavyTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Population</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php foreach( $data as $city => $pop): ?>
<tr>
<td><?= $city ?></td>
<td><?= $pop ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```